Automatic startup of SQL server when configured with SCCM - Who is responsible?
I have configured SCCM with a remote SQL server in the same domain, and it is working fine.
When I stop the SMS_EXECUTIVE service fo SCCM and SQL server in the remote machine, SQL server gets started automatically in a few minutes. I want to know who is responsible for automatically starting the SQL Server after manually stopping it. Before configuring SCCM server with that SQL instance, it never happened.
I have disabled the SQL Server Agent automatic restart of SQL server, so it can't be responsible.

Also I have not setup any recovery actions in services too

I also tried to check in taskschd.msc, don't have a clue on how to check this, attaching a screenshot for reference.

I want to know if SCCM is responsible for this behaviour(if so, how can I confirm that), or any scheduler or something is configured(automatically in the backend like a scheduler) in SQL server machine itself during the configuration of SCCM server.

Is SQL Server installed in a cluster? Maybe the Windows Failover Cluster is restarting it. I’d be surprised is an application such as SCCM we’re starting services on a remote machine.

The Windows Event Log has the data you're looking for, look at service control manager, it's an informational event.

@BrendanMcCaffrey No cluster is configured in both SCCM and remote SQL machines

@SeanGallardy Can you tell me which one to check in that event. I have reproduced the case, and got the service control manager of MSSQL server at the automatic restarted time.
But I [don't/don't know to] find any informative leads from it, can you tell me what parameter to check in the event?
I couldn't share the screenshot of the event properties in the comments.

@Sathisbabu in the event it's the data that says user and comptuer.
